# Pointing a folder subdomain to another IP via Apache

Tags: apache, dns, ip, subdomain

Can you help me? I have two servers with all permissions in CentOS, assigned IPs, and a subdomain that pointing to one, where there a static website. But, the other server has a blog on Wordpress. The question is how pointing from a folder to another server. Thus:

subdomain.domain.com       >>  IP:      1.2.3.4 
subdomain.domain.com/blog  >>  ANOTHER: 2.3.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use something like mod_proxy to reverse proxy requests for blog related resources to your WordPress Server.

So something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
DocumentRoot /whatever
ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

ProxyPass /blog http://2.3.4.5/blog
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://2.3.4.5/blog

#...

</VirtualHost>
```

One more point to mention, in the example above I reverse proxying to a resource identified by the hosts IP address. I would strongly recommend using a hostname and DNS instead since DNS is a good thing:

```
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.domain.com/blog
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.domain.com/blog
```

Obviously you''l need to add 2.3.4.5 to DNS (or host hack accordingly)